# Jobs link title changes (almost) everyday!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed that the link to jobs section in the hamburger button in top left menu (as seen in the pic below) is changing almost everytime I open it!

[image]

It used to be called **Jobs** and then it changed to **Developer Jobs** a few days ago and finally yesterday I opened the menu and it was replaced by **Job Board**

***Why the constant change?***

Comment: A/B testing.... I see Job Search

Comment: @SamuelLiew This doesn't make sense as I'm seeing these changes with my own account. It's really A+B testing

Comment: Now its *Find a Job*

Comment: This is really dumb

Comment: For me it says *Programming Jobs*

Comment: I won’t use until it says “_Find a developer job in the programming job board_”.

Comment: _Browse Jobs_ currently

Comment: They keep raising the stakes. Now I want: _"Browse the programming job board and find a developer job or jobs"_.

Comment: @yivi [Please stop it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg7LX.png) ...

Comment: @rene See? Who wouldn't click on that? Eventually the AI running this A/B/C/D/E/F test will get there.

Comment: @yivi I'm not sure about clicking on it, maybe if they tried a bit harder...

Comment: Can't help but feel they are missing a trick not having "Free Pet Unicorns!" there... Who wouldn't click that?

Comment: I see '*Software Jobs*'.

Comment: I wonder what's next. *Technical Positions*? *Coding Careers*? *Employment Exploration*? *Pursue Programming Professions*?

Comment: Interesting, I thought the title was changing every few hours, but it actually seems to be based on your user agent. Trying on different devices and playing with Chrome UA Spoofer, I see "Programming Jobs" in Chrome on Windows, "Software Jobs" in Chrome on Linux, "Find a Job" with spoofed IE10 user agent, "Job Board" in Chrome on Android (desktop mode), "Developer Jobs" with spoofed Kindle,.... Different versions can have different strings, but it seems consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: I'm a developer on the team that works on the Jobs product.*

As several people concluded, we were running an A/B tests of 8 different variants of the navigation title to see if it impacted the number of people navigating to and utilizing our job search tools.

The variants were:

- Jobs (baseline)
- Find a Job
- Browse Jobs
- Developer Jobs
- Job Board
- Job Search
- Programming Jobs
- Software Jobs

For those interested in the results: we did not see a significant change in the number of people clicking through to the Jobs tooling based on the navigation title variants.

Comment: It probably should have its own section, like teams.

Comment: @Nisarg It should be a link besides `Product` on the top bar